# How to get all cart session from all customer woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i want get all session across customer. I try `WC()->cart->get_cart();` but only return for current user cart.

i try with get direct from database, but still return cart from current user.

```
global $wpdb;

$order_sessions = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT *
    FROM ". $wpdb->prefix."woocommerce_sessions
");
```

Please help, thanks.

Use same browser with different user, ex: user 'A' and 'B'.
Logged in with user 'A' and add to cart product 'XXX', don't check-out, only add to cart. After it, logged out user 'A'.

Logged in again with user 'B' and add to cart product 'XXX', don't check-out, only add to cart. Keep user 'B' logged, and see cart session with this code:

```
global $wpdb;

$order_sessions = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT *
    FROM ". $wpdb->prefix."woocommerce_sessions
");

foreach ( $order_sessions as $order ) {
    print_r(maybe_unserialize($order->session_value));
}
```

Opps, user 'B' can't see user 'A' cart, out-put the code like this:

```
Array
(
    [customer] => a:25:{s:2:"id";i:1;s:8:"postcode";s:5:"36127";s:4:"city";s:10:"Kota Jambi";s:9:"address_1";s:24:"Jalan Lingkar Selatan II";s:7:"address";s:24:"Jalan Lingkar Selatan II";s:9:"address_2";s:14:"RT.025/- No.10";s:5:"state";s:2:"JA";s:7:"country";s:2:"ID";s:17:"shipping_postcode";s:5:"36127";s:13:"shipping_city";s:10:"Kota Jambi";s:18:"shipping_address_1";s:24:"Jalan Lingkar Selatan II";s:16:"shipping_address";s:24:"Jalan Lingkar Selatan II";s:18:"shipping_address_2";s:14:"RT.025/- No.10";s:14:"shipping_state";s:2:"JA";s:16:"shipping_country";s:2:"ID";s:13:"is_vat_exempt";b:0;s:19:"calculated_shipping";b:0;s:10:"first_name";s:8:"Muhammad";s:9:"last_name";s:6:"Rahman";s:7:"company";s:8:"Opsional";s:5:"phone";s:12:"085266769909";s:5:"email";s:21:"idlamalif@yahoo.co.id";s:19:"shipping_first_name";s:8:"Muhammad";s:18:"shipping_last_name";s:6:"Rahman";s:16:"shipping_company";s:8:"Opsional";}
    [cart] => a:1:{s:32:"ca2606a802ac142d2a1587339bde8c15";a:9:{s:10:"product_id";i:22;s:12:"variation_id";i:24;s:9:"variation";a:2:{s:18:"attribute_pa_color";s:5:"green";s:19:"attribute_pa_bentuk";s:12:"tanpa batang";}s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"line_total";i:3000;s:13:"line_subtotal";i:3000;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}}}
    [applied_coupons] => a:0:{}
    [coupon_discount_amounts] => a:0:{}
    [coupon_discount_tax_amounts] => a:0:{}
    [removed_cart_contents] => a:0:{}
    [cart_contents_total] => 3000
    [total] => 0
    [subtotal] => 3000
    [subtotal_ex_tax] => 3000
    [tax_total] => 0
    [taxes] => a:0:{}
    [shipping_taxes] => a:0:{}
    [discount_cart] => 0
    [discount_cart_tax] => 0
    [shipping_total] => 0
    [shipping_tax_total] => 0
    [fee_total] => 0
    [fees] => a:0:{}
)
Array
(
    [customer] => a:25:{s:2:"id";i:4;s:8:"postcode";s:0:"";s:4:"city";s:17:"Kota / Kabupaten*";s:9:"address_1";s:45:"Nama jalan dan nama lorong / gang (jika ada)*";s:7:"address";s:45:"Nama jalan dan nama lorong / gang (jika ada)*";s:9:"address_2";s:24:"RT / RW dan Nomor Rumah*";s:5:"state";s:2:"JA";s:7:"country";s:2:"ID";s:17:"shipping_postcode";s:0:"";s:13:"shipping_city";s:17:"Kota / Kabupaten*";s:18:"shipping_address_1";s:45:"Nama jalan dan nama lorong / gang (jika ada)*";s:16:"shipping_address";s:45:"Nama jalan dan nama lorong / gang (jika ada)*";s:18:"shipping_address_2";s:24:"RT / RW dan Nomor Rumah*";s:14:"shipping_state";s:2:"JA";s:16:"shipping_country";s:2:"ID";s:13:"is_vat_exempt";b:0;s:19:"calculated_shipping";b:0;s:10:"first_name";s:5:"Abdul";s:9:"last_name";s:5:"Manaf";s:7:"company";s:0:"";s:5:"phone";s:2:"12";s:5:"email";s:9:"ui@ui.com";s:19:"shipping_first_name";s:5:"Abdul";s:18:"shipping_last_name";s:5:"Manaf";s:16:"shipping_company";s:0:"";}
)
```

If user 'B' logged out, and login again with user 'A', the result like this:

```
Array
(
    [customer] => a:25:{s:2:"id";i:1;s:8:"postcode";s:5:"36127";s:4:"city";s:10:"Kota Jambi";s:9:"address_1";s:24:"Jalan Lingkar Selatan II";s:7:"address";s:24:"Jalan Lingkar Selatan II";s:9:"address_2";s:14:"RT.025/- No.10";s:5:"state";s:2:"JA";s:7:"country";s:2:"ID";s:17:"shipping_postcode";s:5:"36127";s:13:"shipping_city";s:10:"Kota Jambi";s:18:"shipping_address_1";s:24:"Jalan Lingkar Selatan II";s:16:"shipping_address";s:24:"Jalan Lingkar Selatan II";s:18:"shipping_address_2";s:14:"RT.025/- No.10";s:14:"shipping_state";s:2:"JA";s:16:"shipping_country";s:2:"ID";s:13:"is_vat_exempt";b:0;s:19:"calculated_shipping";b:0;s:10:"first_name";s:8:"Muhammad";s:9:"last_name";s:6:"Rahman";s:7:"company";s:8:"Opsional";s:5:"phone";s:12:"085266769909";s:5:"email";s:21:"idlamalif@yahoo.co.id";s:19:"shipping_first_name";s:8:"Muhammad";s:18:"shipping_last_name";s:6:"Rahman";s:16:"shipping_company";s:8:"Opsional";}
)
Array
(
    [customer] => a:25:{s:2:"id";i:4;s:8:"postcode";s:0:"";s:4:"city";s:17:"Kota / Kabupaten*";s:9:"address_1";s:45:"Nama jalan dan nama lorong / gang (jika ada)*";s:7:"address";s:45:"Nama jalan dan nama lorong / gang (jika ada)*";s:9:"address_2";s:24:"RT / RW dan Nomor Rumah*";s:5:"state";s:2:"JA";s:7:"country";s:2:"ID";s:17:"shipping_postcode";s:0:"";s:13:"shipping_city";s:17:"Kota / Kabupaten*";s:18:"shipping_address_1";s:45:"Nama jalan dan nama lorong / gang (jika ada)*";s:16:"shipping_address";s:45:"Nama jalan dan nama lorong / gang (jika ada)*";s:18:"shipping_address_2";s:24:"RT / RW dan Nomor Rumah*";s:14:"shipping_state";s:2:"JA";s:16:"shipping_country";s:2:"ID";s:13:"is_vat_exempt";b:0;s:19:"calculated_shipping";b:0;s:10:"first_name";s:5:"Abdul";s:9:"last_name";s:5:"Manaf";s:7:"company";s:0:"";s:5:"phone";s:2:"12";s:5:"email";s:9:"ui@ui.com";s:19:"shipping_first_name";s:5:"Abdul";s:18:"shipping_last_name";s:5:"Manaf";s:16:"shipping_company";s:0:"";}
    [cart] => a:1:{s:32:"ca2606a802ac142d2a1587339bde8c15";a:9:{s:10:"product_id";i:22;s:12:"variation_id";i:24;s:9:"variation";a:2:{s:18:"attribute_pa_color";s:5:"green";s:19:"attribute_pa_bentuk";s:12:"tanpa batang";}s:8:"quantity";i:2;s:10:"line_total";i:6000;s:13:"line_subtotal";i:6000;s:8:"line_tax";i:0;s:17:"line_subtotal_tax";i:0;s:13:"line_tax_data";a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}}}
    [applied_coupons] => a:0:{}
    [coupon_discount_amounts] => a:0:{}
    [coupon_discount_tax_amounts] => a:0:{}
    [removed_cart_contents] => a:0:{}
    [cart_contents_total] => 6000
    [total] => 0
    [subtotal] => 6000
    [subtotal_ex_tax] => 6000
    [tax_total] => 0
    [taxes] => a:0:{}
    [shipping_taxes] => a:0:{}
    [discount_cart] => 0
    [discount_cart_tax] => 0
    [shipping_total] => 0
    [shipping_tax_total] => 0
    [fee_total] => 0
    [fees] => a:0:{}
)
```

Why? can you explain it?

Comment: I agree that code work fine, but you can see "cart" variable only for current user, not for all user.

Test with:
Open two browser, one browser for A user and one again for B user.
'A' user add to cart item 'XXX' and user 'B' add it again ('XXX').

Now, get data with my code. You can see 'CART' variable only for one user.

'A' can't see 'B' cart, and 'B' can't see 'A' cart, i want ALL user can see ALL CART from across user.

Comment: Please test it with only registered and logged in user can add to cart.

Comment: The problem find! If your test it with ONE browser, user 'A' add to cart and logged out, login again with user 'B' and add to cart.

Now, you as user 'B' can't see user 'A' cart.,